# Setting up a DNS without owning a domain

Tags: dns

I have been researching on how to set up a DNS server and found that BIND seems to be the best way to do so. I am new to setting up a DNS server so I have a couple of questions

I do not own a domain name, would it be possible to still set up a DNS server with a fake domain name and still be able to test out the features as needed?

Comment: Hard to know what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can install bind9:
apt-get install bind9

You don't need a domain to have a DNS server. If you wanted you could setup, say, your laptop or desktop to a static IP and configure bind9 to translate "laptop" to 192.168.1.10
you could also ping "laptop" and it would resolve laptop to 192.168.1.10

If you wanted to, you could setup to use it as the primary DNS server and have bind9 forward external requests to google 8.8.4.4 or any other DNS server of your choice.

Comment: You can even create your own domain, like ".myhome" and direct traffic on your own LAN to "laptop.myhome". Just don't expect traffic from the Internet to know where laptop.myhome is.